# first transaction in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

My aim is to get the first transaction for a group of customers in a sub query and then average them out. this is the query that i am using:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ON (account_id) created_at AS "first_transaction_date"
, account_id
, money_amount
FROM    transactions
WHERE   status = 'accepted'
```

and I am getting the following data

```
first_transaction_date  account_id  Money_amount
2017-05-01              1           25
```

My issue is that I am getting the wrong information as this is not the first transaction for this customer.

Appreciate any help.

thanks in advance

Stefan

P.S. this is my first time posting here, so my apologies if I missed anything

Comment: Minimal sample data and desired result would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sorting on anything, and PostgreSQL can't guarantee row order to be in the creation order.
It should be enough to just add an order by clause like this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ON (account_id) created_at AS "first_transaction_date"
, account_id
, money_amount
FROM    transactions
WHERE   status = 'accepted'
ORDER BY account_id, created_at
```